# Hadoop LZO Native libraries & JAR not available

Tags: hadoop, native, lzo

I downloaded Hadoop 1.1.2 from http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2-bin.tar.gz. Its native directory does not have LZO native libs.

$ find ~/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/

```
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-i386-32
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-i386-32/libhadoop.so
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-i386-32/libhadoop.la
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-i386-32/libhadoop.a
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-i386-32/libhadoop.so.1
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-i386-32/libhadoop.so.1.0.0

/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhadoop.so
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhadoop.la
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhadoop.a
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhadoop.so.1
/home/deepakkv/softwares/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
```

$

When i run a PIG script using PigServer in local mode, i see the following error

parquet.hadoop.BadConfigurationException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec was not found

How can i get the jar file and natives ?

Answer (score 2):

LZO is GPL licensed so it can't be shipped with hadoop (unlike snappy which is BSD based)
you can build LZO from https://github.com/toddlipcon/hadoop-lzo or download from https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-gpl-packing/